# How do I disable just one cipher out of OpenSSL TLSv1.3 list?

Tags: nginx, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, cipher

I use Nginx + Let's Encrypt with OpenSSL on my server. I wanted to use TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3. But I wanted to use very specific SSL ciphers. Specifically:

- `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` (TLSv1.3),
- `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` (TLSv1.3),
- `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` (TLSv1.2),
- `ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` (TLSv1.2),
- `DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` (TLSv1.2),
- `DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` (TLSv1.2),

but not `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` (TLSv1.3). I have done multiple configuration on Nginx configuration file to disable this cipher but it didn't work. Some of them are:

- `ssl_ciphers "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305";` - Adding double quotes
- `ssl_ciphers "!TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305";` - Adding `!` to that cipher
- `ssl_ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` - Without double quotes

So how do I achieve this? Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

Nginx doesn't support configuring TLS 1.3 cipher suites like this, and you shouldn't, as per [RFC 8446, 9.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-9.1) there are *Mandatory-to-Implement Cipher Suites*.

> A TLS-compliant application MUST implement the `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`
> [[GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#ref-GCM)] cipher suite and SHOULD implement the `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`
> [[GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#ref-GCM)] and `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` [[RFC8439](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8439)] cipher suites (see
> [Appendix B.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#appendix-B.4)).

If you really want to mess with this, you'd have to disable the mandatory cipher suite in the *OpenSSL CONF library configuration files* [`openssl.cnf`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html) as explained in e.g. [Perfect 100 SSL-Labs Score Revisited](https://dawnbringer.net/blog/1083/TLS%20All%20The%20Things!%20Perfect%20ssl-labs%20score%20for%20Nginx):

> ```
> [system_default_sect] 
> MinProtocol = TLSv1.2 
> CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2 
> Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 
> Options = ServerPreference,PrioritizeChaCha 
> ...
> ```
>
> This will state to your OS that the minimum TLS version used is TLS1.2
> and the Ciphersuites to use ar the ones specified. Please note that I
> have only specified TLS1.3 suites. If you need TLS1.2 support, do add
> "some" of them.

Comment: Note that if you do this, you won't be able to communicate via TLS 1.3 with a minimal TLS 1.3 implementation that only has TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. I'm not aware of any such implementation right now, but there probably is one out there somewhere, maybe in IoT devices...

Comment: I would try this in an hour. This looks promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As of nginx 1.19 this is possible:

```
ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256;
```

Now you will be able to score 100%, but you will be violating standards. So after looking at this round 100% metric, I'd suggest disabling that.